# UITableView's footer is not visible while scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a scenario where my Table holds list of products. This list has a footerView with a button added to the footerView. I could able to see/scroll complete footerView along with the button when I open the already created Product List. But I cannot see complete button in the footerView when I create & Save the Product list for the first time.

I am using below code:

```
UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_SIZE_WIDTH, 44)];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, SCREEN_SIZE_WIDTH - 20, 44);

[footerView addSubview:button];
self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView;

[self.tableView setTableFooterView:footerView];//Tried this one too
```

Please help me to show/scroll the button in footerView. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, its working fine for me:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(array.count>1){
            if(indexPath.row == array.count-1){
                [self setupTableViewFooter];
            }
    }
}


- (void)setupTableViewFooter
{
    // set up label
    UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)];
    footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:Font_MuseoSans size:14];
    label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    label.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    label.text = @"Loading";

    self.footerLabel = label;
    CGSize labelSize = [self.footerLabel sizeThatFits:footerView.frame.size];
    [footerView addSubview:self.footerLabel];

    // set up activity indicator
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activityIndicatorView.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    activityIndicatorView.color = [UIColor blackColor];

    self.activityIndicator = activityIndicatorView;
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

    [footerView addSubview:self.activityIndicator];

    CGRect footerFrame = footerView.frame;
    label.frame = CGRectMake((footerFrame.size.width-labelSize.width - 4 - activityIndicatorView.frame.size.width)/2, (footerFrame.size.height-labelSize.height)/2
                             , (footerFrame.size.width-labelSize.width - 4 - activityIndicatorView.frame.size.width), labelSize.height);
    self.activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x + labelSize.width + 4, (footerFrame.size.height-activityIndicatorView.frame.size.height)/2
                                              , activityIndicatorView.frame.size.width, activityIndicatorView.frame.size.height);

    self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView;
}
```

Comment: No, it did not help! Still the issue exists.